# Best way to represent time duration in a log entry

Tags: c#, logging, timespan

I'm writing a simple generic logger class, that is aware of time started and ended of a task that is being logged.

In English how would you rather see represented the time taken for the task to finish in various time figures?

I currently have,

```
Log("Finished in {0}ms, {1}s, {2}m.", ts.TotalMilliseconds, ts.TotalSeconds, ts.TotalMinutes);
```

Which outputs,

2012-02-16@20:12:33: Finished in 2007.8125ms, 2.0078125s, 0.0334635416666667m.

Any better ways you may suggest?

Cheers,
P.

Thanks Xeno, final code is:

```
Log(string.Concat("Finished in ", (ts.Hours > 0 ? ts.Hours + "h " : string.Empty),
                                    (ts.Minutes > 0 ? ts.Minutes + "m " : string.Empty),
                                    (ts.Seconds > 0 ? ts.Seconds + "s " : string.Empty),
                                    (ts.Milliseconds > 0 ? ts.Milliseconds + "ms " : string.Empty),
                                    ("(" + ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("0.000") + ")")));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
0h 0m 2s 7.815ms
```

Since its a generic Logger, this was generic suggestion

The best way would be to give the user a way to define this in a configuration file or at least programmatically at initialization time

Comment: yap that's what I though also, any reason why the precision . on milliseconds? in C# TimeSpan.Milliseconds is an int.

Comment: TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds will give you a fractional representation of milliseconds as a double. You could always do mod 1000 to get the value in the above example- or you could trim it to full milliseconds. It really depends on what this is being used for and the amount of precision required. Although I would imagine the cases that require the highest level of precision would use stopwatch directly.

Comment: have gone for this, and added totalmilliseconds in brackets, thanks Xeno.

Answer (score 2):

**My personal preference is using some standard**. Because they are standard and easy to parse later.

For example, [HTTP/1.1 Date/Time format](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3) which yields any of the following format.

```
  Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT  ; RFC 822, updated by RFC 1123
  Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT ; RFC 850, obsoleted by RFC 1036
  Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994       ; ANSI C's asctime() format
```

Along with this Its better to store the **Unix Timestamp**. Its always comes handy.

Lastly Put the **time duration in miliseconds**. If you have miliseconds you can convert it to any other higher unit. However if you want someone else will read it put it in `HH:MM:SS.fff` or similar format. This format is easier to understand.

Comment: valid points, but in this case the log is to be looked at by a person, therefore I'd like to represent in a way a human would best read the time duration.

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply log the begin and end times to their highest precision, which is probably the most flexible or accurate representation.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on context. If you have a process that typically runs for several minutes, milliseconds is irrelevant. If you have something that runs in a few seconds, milliseconds may be relevant. If it's under 1 second, definitely millis or micros.

Comment: it may run tasks of various durations. should have mentioned that, sorry.

Comment: Then you should have it dynamically choose the format based on run times: Show millis by default, but if over, say, 60s don't show millis, if over 20 minutes, don't show seconds, if over 100 hours don't show minutes, etc.
   This is what gmail and SO do to show elapsed times.

Comment: Actually, I like @Xeno's answer best.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to vary between milliseconds and hours, then I'd stick with a consistent yet familiar notation:

```
HH:mm:ss.fff
```